# Get Inactive Users Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

```
ga:daysSinceLastSession >= 20
```

says. 400 : Invalid value 'ga:daysSinceLastSession >= 20' for filters parameter.

But according to the manual that's way you should do it. So what am I doing wrong here?

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=REMOVED&dimensions=ga%3AdaysSinceLastSession&metrics=ga%3Ausers&segment=gaid%3A%3A-14&filters=ga%3AdaysSinceLastSession%20%3E%3D%2020&start-date=2014-05-12&end-date=2014-05-14&max-results=50
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ga:daysSinceLastSession](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=user&jump=ga_dayssincelastsession)  is a dimension.  Dimensons can only be filtered on

- == Exact match
- != Does not match
- =@ Contains substring
- !@ Does not contain substring
- =~ Contains a match for the regular expression
- !~ Does not match regular expression !~

Answer: `'ga:daysSinceLastSession >= 20'` is an invalid use of a filter because you cant do >= on a dimension.

Link to filters with the Core reporting api:  [Filteres](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters)

Edit:
The only option I can think of would be a very scary filter something like `ga:daysSinceLastSession==10,ga:daysSinceLastSession==11,ga:daysSinceLastSession==12`

Note: I'm not sure how long a filter can be documentation says 128 characters for regular expression filters but I'm not sure if that limit will apply here.  But the max length of a URL is 2000 characters so you will have to test the max length of your request string as you build it.

Comment: That's they only thing I can think of. Its ugly but it does work.  You can test it here: http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/  but really if you only want to test the ones that are grater then 10 why not just grab them all and chuck out the ones you don't want in your code.

Comment: I have no sample data to work with, so this is scary and Im not sure what to expect. Can you describe what your filter above does? I don't get it

Comment: , is means or. so its basically: ga:daysSinceLastSession==10  or ga:daysSinceLastSession==11 or ga:daysSinceLastSession==12 ...

Answer (score 0):

[Data Type for daysSinceLastSession is String](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=user&jump=ga_dayssincelastsession), so I guess a mathematical operator won't work (equality operator works fine in the query explorer). I think you'd have to go for an regular expression (at least two numbers, first numbers 2 or larger).

Comment: Not really tested, but it should work something like ga:daysSinceLastSession=~[2-9][0-9]+ ( "=~" denotes a regular expression, you need to have at least two numbers the first of which must be two or larger).